# Some problems with Threads

Tags: java

I'm having a-bit of trouble with threads in java. Basically Im creating an array of threads and starting them. the point of the program is to simulate a race, total the time for each competitor ( i.e. each thread ) and pick the winner.

The competitor moves one space, waits ( i.e. thread sleeps for a random period of time between 5 and 6 seconds ) and then continues. The threads don't complete in the order that they started as expected.

Now for the problem. I can get the total time it takes for a thread to complete; what I want is to store all the times from the threads into a single array and be able to calculate the fastest time.

To do this should I place the array in the main.class file? Would I be right in assuming so because if it was placed in the Thread class it wouldn't work. Or should I create a third class?

I'm alittle confused :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fine to declare it in the method where you invoke the threads, with a few notes:

- each thread should know its index in the array. Perhaps you should pass this in constructor
- then you have three options for filling the array

  - the array should be `final`, so that it can be used within anonymous classes
  - the array can be passed to each thread
  - the threads should notify a listener when they're done, which in turn will increment an array.
- consider using [Java 1.5 Executors framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) for submitting Runnables, rather than working directly with threads.

Comment: I would suggest to use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of array

Comment: yes, will work as well, and the threads should not be aware of their index.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies - Im working to implement it all now. BTW considering a shared variable is involved could i make use of the keyword volatile? Or is this overkill because the threads will write to different positions in the array?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: The solution below assumes you need the times only *after* all competitors have finished the race.

You can use a structure that looks like below, (inside your main class). Typically you want to add a lot of you own stuff; this is the main outline.

Note that concurrency is not an issue at all here because you get the value from the `MyRunnable` instance once its thread has finished running.

Note that using a separate thread for each competitor is probably not really necessary with a modified approach, but that would be a different issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyRunnable[] runnables = new MyRunnable[NUM_THREADS];
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[NUM_THREADS];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        runnables[i] = new MyRunnable();
        threads[i] = new Thread(runnables[i]);
    }

    // start threads
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        thread.start();
    }

    // wait for threads
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ignored
        }
    }

    // get the times you calculated for each thread
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        int timeSpent = runnables[i].getTimeSpent();
        // do something with the time spent
    }
}

static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private int timeSpent;        

    public MyRunnable(...) {
        // initialize
    }

    public void run() {
        // whatever the thread should do

        // finally set the time
        timeSpent = ...;
    }

    public int getTimeSpent() {
        return timeSpent;
    }
}
```